# passport.use jwt pass role parameter

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

How can i pass additional parameter (role that will have access to this api) to the passport jwt authenticate function ?

I want to add role check inside it, but I can't pass the role.
here it is how it looks like:

```
passport.use(
    'jwt',
    new JWTstrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        try {...
```

And this is from where it is being called:

```
app.post('/addFeature', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) =>{...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass more parameters to JWT auth function.

Here is what I use for this scenario.

First I assume that your JWTs have the user role info in their payload. Passport is just for authenticating JWT. It checks if JWT is valid or not. If it is valid it parses the JWT payload for you to use.

[This code is from official documentation of Passport JWT](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/)

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, false);
        }
        if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    });
}));
```

As you can see, it finds the user by using JWT SUB from parsed JWT.

```
jwt_payload.sub
```

If you put your roles in your JWT you can do something like:

```
jwt_payload.roles
```

Then notice that, if the user found it calls done with second parameter "user". It is just giving something to passport to be put in request object. So you can use it from your requst object like:

```
req.user
```

Now instead of passing a user instance, you can pass a user object.

```
const user = {
    instance: user,
    roles: jwt_payload.roles // or what is ok for you
}

return done(null, user);
```

Now remember, ExpressJS middleware logic. You can create a role checker middleware and use it after jwt authentication method.

```
const roleCheckMiddleware = (req, res, next, roles) => {
    // if req.roles does not contain given roles, return response with status code forbidden.
};
```

And define your route with necessary calls.

```
app.post(
    '/addFeature',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}),
    (req, res, next) => { roleCheckMiddleware(req, res, next, ['admin', 'manager'] }
);
```

Comment: I missed jwt.sign part, and that was making my life miserable. Thank you for thorough post it helped a lot. I have added sending to client instantly res.send(400).. inside role check function, but if there is another error, it gives multiple sending to client not allowed. I am using res.headersSent to check in future responses, any better logic ?

Comment: I use return res.sendStatus(403); for permission related authorization failures. You can't use the res object after you send a response back. So it is a good practice to always return with res.send methods. Your error's reason is you are trying to use res object after sending the response back.